# Android: Why setImageResource changes several images in my listView/onListItemClick?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-imageview

My application has a questionnaire which is displayed thanks to a listView.
The user can answer by true or false by clicking the ListItem.
An imageView indicates that the answer is true. (I change the imageView each time the ListItem is clicked)

Globally it works fine. I have been able to change the imageView dynamically but surprisingly when I use **setImageResource**, the image **changes on several lines.**
For istance, If I click the row 2 (index 1), the image changes on row 2 but also on rows 12 and 22.

For the moment I haven't been able to find the solution.
I would be grateful if you have any clue for me.

Here is the layout of my listitem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="30dp"
 >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/ivCheck"
    android:layout_width="25dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:contentDescription="selection state"
    android:src="@drawable/check_grey" />


<TextView
android:id="@+id/tvId"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textIsSelectable="false"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:text="dummy text"
android:visibility="gone"
/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvText"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:layout_marginLeft="14dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/ivCheck"
    android:text="dummy text"
    android:textIsSelectable="false" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my method changing the image (in a listActivity)

```
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {     
ImageView image = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.ivCheck);
QuizAnswer currentQuizAnswer = (QuizAnswer) quizRequest.getListAnswers().get(position);
if(currentQuizAnswer.isSelected()) {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_grey);
} else {
    image.setImageResource(R.drawable.check_green);
}
currentQuizAnswer.setSelected(!currentQuizAnswer.isSelected());
}
```

Thank you in advanced for your help

Comment: Is your list displayed correctly? By any chance do you have those items repeated? Probably they are the same View so that's why it's acting like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is due to views' recycling in ListView. You need to **override** `getView` method of your adapter and reset the source for your ImageViews which does not relate with the previous change.

For more info, read [**this**](http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/) or watch [**this**](http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html) video.

Comment: The behaviour was not easy to understand.
Thank you for these useful links.

Comment: Yes, it is a difficult topic at start but once you start working on this you'll find it easy

Answer (score 0):

change single line and see the magic

```
position = position % (QuizAnswer) quizRequest.getListAnswers().size();
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to apply custom adapter to the listview.
Check these links:

[Link 1](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)
[Link 2](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html)
[Link 3](http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429)
[Link 4](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-listview-example/). Hope this will prove helpful to you. Also have a look at [The world of listview.](http://chintansoni202.wordpress.com/2013/02/12/the-world-of-listview/) Your doubts will definitely be solved, such a nice tutorial this is.